# getBalance and getBlock not working web3 with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

**here is an example of getting the first 10 blocks**
I tried this and nothing comes back. No errors either.

```
export const useBlock = async () => {
  const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
  const blocks: BlockTransactionString[]  = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    web3.eth.getBlockNumber(async (error, number) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
      const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(number);
      blocks.push(block);
    });
  }

  return blocks;
};
```

---

**here is the Block.tsx file**

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";

interface BlockProps {
  block: any;
}

const Block: React.FC<BlockProps> = ({ block }) => {
  return (
    <Card className="p-4">
      <p className="fs-6">Block number: {block.number}</p>
      <p className="fs-6">Block timestamp: {block.timestamp}</p>
      <p className="fs-6">Block hash: {block.hash}</p>
      <p className="fs-6">Block parent hash: {block.parentHash}</p>
      <p className="fs-6">Block nonce: {block.nonce}</p>
      <p className="fs-6">Block difficulty: {block.difficulty}</p>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Block;
```

---

**and here is the Blocks.tsx file**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
 import { useBlock } from "../hooks/useBlock";
import BlockTransactionString from "web3-eth";
import Block from "./Block";

const Blocks = () => {
  const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState<
    BlockTransactionString.BlockTransactionString[]
  >([]);

  const set10Blocks = async () => {
    const blocks = await useBlock();
    setBlocks(blocks);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    set10Blocks();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {blocks.map((block) => (
        <Block block={block} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Blocks;
```

I expect to have 10 cards with the block info on them (block info being what is in Block.tsx).

Other information: `web3.eth.getBalance()` also does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write a hook but you are actually just writing a plain function. react hook means you are going to add logic into "React state and lifecycle features from function components.". That means in case of rerendering you have to present the updated state to the component. this should be your hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export const useBlock = async (web3) => {
  const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState([]);
  const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

  useEffect(() => {
    // if you are accessing "window" in Next.js make sure do this in useEffect where "window" is already defined before component mounts
    // web3 methods returns promise, I need an async function defined inside
    // this arg web3" name can be any name 
    const getBlocks = async (web3) => {
      let blocks: BlockTransactionString[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const blockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
        const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber);
        blocks.push(block);
      }
      return blocks;
    };
    const blocks = getBlocks(web3).catch((error) => console.error(error));
    setBlocks(blocks);
  }, [web3]);

  return { blocks };
};
```

Inside `Blocks.tsx`

```
  // if Web3 changes, this will create a new instance
  const web3 = useMemo(() => new Web3(window.ethereum), [Web3]);

  // inside useBlocks web3 is also dependency for the useEffect
  // so if web3 changes, it will rerender
  const {blocks}=useBlocks(web3)
  console.log(blocks)
```